# A evolutionary triple relating to Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, dual-spaces

In Brezis's functional analysis(p.291), it says the following

> $$W_0^{1,p}(\Omega) \subset L^2(\Omega) \subset W^{-1, p'}(\Omega) \quad \mbox{if} \quad 2N/(N+2) \le p \le 2$$

whether $\Omega$ is bounded or not bounded.  As far as I know, most of Sobolev's inequalities or embeddings apply to bounded domains. Would you explain why the first inclusion holds? What Sobolev inequalities should we use to prove that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space $W^{1,p}_0$ is continuously embedded into $L^q$ for $\frac1q=\frac1p-\frac1N$ (Thm 9.9 in Brezis).
The value of $q$ is larger than $2$ iff $\frac12\ge\frac1q=\frac1p-\frac1N$ or equivalently $p\ge \frac{2N}{N+2}$. Then we know: $W^{1,p}\subset L^q \cap L^p$,
and since $p \le 2\le q$, $W^{1,p}\subset L^2$ by Hoelder inequality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! By the way, in Thm 9.9, $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^N$. Is this true for when $\Omega$ is a proper (unbounded) open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$,?

Comment: yes, if $u\in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ then $u\in W^{1,p}(R^N)$, see Remark 20 after Prop 9.18

Comment: Thank you SOOOOO much !! Oh, Sobolev space....  